# android studio keeps forcing emulated sd card when running on device, cannot stop it

Tags: android

I'm just try to transfer over data from my app to my new cell phone but all the basic apps only lets me transfer the app and none of its data.

I have created a app that lets me store information on my phone in a txt file, but I need to move it to my new phone. I would like to have an export/import function instead of just hardcoding the data into a new version of the app.

Only problem, I cannot access the SD card when I run 'app' from android studio (To the device thru USB). It does not matter if the SD card is installed or not, It just keeps defaulting to an emulated SD card. Tried switching SD's between phones (file not found). I have mostly installed the app thru running in android studio to my phone. Maybe that is why I cannot access the SD card, because a setting is wrong somewhere?

Is there a way to make android studio stop using emulated drives and make it use only physical drives?

if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
Is always true

Found the files here, but not on my SD card
Tons of variations of:
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "dbimport.txt");

All give the same-

Device Manager:
shell/emulated/0/filename

from app:
Storage/emulated/0/filename

Comment: You are talking a lot. And about different problems which makes it unclear where you need help. It looks to me that your Android app is unable to determine the path to an SD card. Is that all? Then why didnt you just say that?

Comment: How can I get my app to not default to that emulated card and instead write to the physical card is my main question. because all my code works its just not transferable since its on a emulated card instead of the real card.

Comment: Well your app can write to the SD card as soon as it determines/knows the full path to the card. For the rest you can use the same code of course.

Comment: `All give the same-

Device Manager: shell/emulated/0/filename

from app: Storage/emulated/0/filename`? Where did you see such paths? What kind of file explorer did you use? Those are non existing paths. The real paths you will see with myFile.getAbsolutePath(). Please tell value.